# boost::asio internal queue capacity

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I was attempting to understand Boost Asio implementation and limitations. As I understand from here - https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/basics.html

When you do an async_receive_from call on a socket, the following things happen

1. The socket forwards the request to the I/O execution context.
2. The I/O execution context signals to the operating system that it should start an asynchronous connect.
3. The operating system indicates that the connect operation has completed by placing the result on a queue, ready to be picked up by the I/O execution context.
4. When using an io_context as the I/O execution context, your program must make a call to io_context::run() (or to one of the similar io_context member functions) in order for the result to be retrieved. A call to io_context::run() blocks while there are unfinished asynchronous operations, so you would typically call it as soon as you have started your first asynchronous operation.

Assuming I have very high throughput of data coming in, what I'm trying to understand is

1. Is there a possibility of data loss in step 2 above where IO execution context signals OS to perform the async receive operation? Can the OS get somehow overwhelmed with the volume of asynchronous reads?
2. In step 3 above, OS puts completed reads in a queue. What is the capacity of this queue? Can this queue overflow if for example, there was a burst of network traffic and all the threads running io_context::run() are occupied, hence read data keeps accumulating in the queue? Is this queue bounded or unbounded?

The ASIO code is open-source, but I'm fairly new to C++ and am finding it a little difficult to understand the code. Appreciate any help on these questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no buffering in ASIO whatsoever; ASIO is a thin wrapper around native OS `select`/`epoll`/`kqueue`/`IOCP` (depending on OS) as well as non-blocking `send`/`recv` calls.

Your question can thus be re-phased as "*what happens when I don't call `recv` fast enough?*". As it turns out, that question has already been asked before, see  [What happens if one doesn't call POSIX's `recv` “fast enough”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700836/what-happens-if-one-doesnt-call-posixs-recv-fast-enough).

Anyway, to answer the specific questions:

> 1. Is there a possibility of data loss in step 2 above where IO execution context signals OS to perform the async receive operation? Can the OS get somehow overwhelmed with the volume of asynchronous reads?

The OS can't get overwhelmed with async receive calls because you can have at most 1 active async receive and send per socket, and the number of sockets is limited.

> 2. ... What is the capacity of this queue? Can this queue overflow if for example, there was a burst of network traffic and all the threads running io_context::run() are occupied, hence read data keeps accumulating in the queue? Is this queue bounded or unbounded?

The queueing characteristics of a TCP stream are determined by the TCP receive buffer and TCP receive window. These are configurable in most modern OSes, and can even by dynamic. The receive buffer is bounded, and if you don't receive fast enough, TCP has built-in mechanisms to signal the sending side to slow down/retransmit (a.k.a. TCP Flow Control).

Similarly UDP has a receive buffer. When that one gets full, new incoming packets are dropped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A follow up question. When we run an event loop using io_context::run(), does it poll the UDP/TCP receive buffer? I was assuming it polls some internal queue filled with completed reads.

Comment: Yes, run() invokes select/epoll/kqueue/GetQueuedCompletionStatus, thus polling the sockets for completed reads/writes/.. if we trim away all of ASIO abstractions then the program will boil down to [this](https://gist.github.com/reterVision/8300781).